# In TypeScript, How do I go about adding a property to an object type in an Interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I am trying to understand how to merge declare an interface, but instead of adding a field to the interface itself, I wish to add a property to the object literal type.

I have a type defined in a library as follows:

```
interface DefaultSession {
    user?: {
      name?: string | null;
      email?: string | null;
      image?: string | null;
    };
    expires: ISODateString;
}
```

I know that if I wanted to add a field to this interface without changing the name, I could simply reopen and declare:

```
interface DefaultSession {
    role?: string
}
```

I have been studying the Typescript Handbook, but I can't find a way to merge declare role as a property under user to yield a type as follows:

```
interface DefaultSession {
    user?: {
        name?: string | null;
        email?: string | null;
        image?: string | null;
        role?: string | null;
    };
    expires: ISODateString;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is intersection type:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html

Just declare your custom type like following:

```
interface DefaultSession {
  user?: {
    name?: string | null;
    email?: string | null;
    image?: string | null;
  };
  expires: ISODateString;
}

type CustomDefaultSession = DefaultSession & {
  user?: {
    role?: string | null;
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like it is or implement it for your class. Besides if you want the same name for your custom type then just refer library type using alias.

If you have a callback inside library you can override argument type like the following:

```
// Callback defined inside the library.
type LibraryCallback = (defaultSession: DefaultSession) => void;

// Function inside the library which accepts callback.
function libraryFunction(libraryCallback: LibraryCallback): void
{
    // Do stuff...
}

// Application code which calls library function and changes callback argument type.
libraryFunction((customDefaultSession: CustomDefaultSession) =>
{
    const role = customDefaultSession.user.role;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that input.  What I am trying to do is to get the session callback as defined in the next-auth library to accept the role information as part of the session token without rewriting that library.  It is trivial to do in JS as I simply add the role to that object.  I can also easily do that if I simply declare role as a new field on DefaultSession interface as opposed to a property on the user object.

Comment: What stops you from using defined custom type as a type hint for an argument? As it extends one provided by the library there should not be any issues. You cannot replace type inside the library but you can tell TypeScript about your intention. I've extended answer with an example.

Answer (score 2):

Just do the following:

```
export interface Foo {
    user?: {
      name?: string | null;
      email?: string | null;
      image?: string | null;
    };
    expires: Date;
}


export interface Bar extends Foo {
  user?: Foo['user'] & {
    role?: string
  }
}
```

First, extend the `Bar` form `Foo` and assign the `user` just like above with `&` sign. `&` merges two object types. Thus you get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, as I mentioned to dpimonov above, I am trying to get a function in an existing library to accept that extra tidbit of information.  I am not sure that this is good practice, but it is very easy to implement in pure JS.

Comment: You can use your version of the `type` in your app by extending the `type` from the third-party library like above.